# How do I know if my boss is angry with me?

Tags: email

I just start working on a company as an internship developer. Due to these weeks are my final exam week so I only can go to work 2 days per week. I already worked on Monday and Tuesday this week and I also told my boss I'll come work on Friday morning.

Yesterday my university's tutor changed the time of an important revision session to the morning today. So I emailed my boss and said I can't work today and really apologized.

This is what he replied:'Thanks, Seamas. Just figure out how to meet timelines with the different priorities.' I am not sure if he is mad at me. Feels really bad now, what should I reply him? Is he mad at me?

Thanks every one who contribute the answer, really appreciated you guys

Comment: Please remember your education comes first.  Your boss couldn't care less if you fail, he's obviously only interested in cheap labor.  Look after yourself and your education.

Comment: @solarflare. Wow! Talk about a ridiculously negative interpretation from limited data! In fact, internship developers are frequently only marginally useful because the amount of time needed to train and guide them detracts from work down by more productive employees. Many bosses will take internships not because they're "cheap labour" but because they wish to perform a socially useful service to their community.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't infer anger from that email (or anything else about him as a manager.)  It's short, possibly because he was busy at the time, but I see no reason his words should be taken with any particular emotional context.  He's basically just asking that you do what you need to do so that this change won't impact his deadlines

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is he mad at me?

The only way you will know is if you **ask them**.

When you do this, be sure to spell out what happened, including the fact that the schedule was changed by the university's tutor, and that it was out of your control.  If your boss has questions answer them honestly.

I also suggest, if your studies/schedule allows for it, to **put in some time** (*on the weekend perhaps*) to get the work done.  Ultimately your boss is concerned with meeting his or her obligations too.

Comment: This truly is the best response.  Being direct with people at least gives you the cover of "I asked you directly if it was an issue" if it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 16):

You are overthinking this. It might be a cultural thing, but I actually cannot find a single indication of the boss being mad .

```
'Thanks, Seamas. Just figure out how to meet timelines with the different priorities.'
```

The above response seems very neutral. In fact, it sounds like the boss wants you to manage your own time. You are at an early stage of your career and the boss is merely gently letting you know how time management is generally handled.

Comment: +1, I can't see anything that suggests he's mad at all. If anything, it sounds like he trusts you to manage your own time well - I'd take that as a positive.

Answer (score -1):

The ultimate question is if he is indeed mad with you, does it really matter? You're the intern, and working free labor. If your boss told you he needed you in such that you'd miss your revision, what would take priority? Your future, or your boss?

Aside from that, reading in what your boss said, it sounds like an advice. He's saying get your priorities right and then come back to him. Sounds like he's saying you should gather the facts before emailing and that is typically sound advice to avoid mass emailing each step of the way.

Answer (score -1):

Even if your boss is mad at you it's not so important.  As your manager he should be capable to contain their emotions and keep the relationship professional.

I can imagine myself giving similar feedback as your boss did, and my message in this case would mean:

- Yes, sure emergencies do happen, so do whatever you need to fulfil your other obligations.
- However bear in mind that this kind of thing can not happen endlessly and at some point I expect you to show your commitment to your job, that is prioritize in favor of it and not something else.
- Actually, given that you are still intern, this is a very good opportunity for you to learn how to handle conflicting obligations because that's something you will be doing for the rest of your life.

Now if you demonstrate that you understand all that through your actions, and show your boss that you appreciate the flexibility you were given and by no means take it for granted then even if they *were* mad at you that should pass.